# Update a table after x minutes/hours

Tags: django, postgresql, triggers

I have these tables

```
exam(id, start_date, deadline, duration)
exam_answer(id, exam_id, answer, time_started, status)
```

exam_answer.status possible values are 0-not yet started 1-started 2-submitted

Is there a way to update exam_answer.status once now - exam_answer.time_started is greater than exam.duration? Or if it is already past deadline?

I'll also mentioning this if it might help me better, I'm building this for a django project.

Comment: could you clarify? it's a bit unclear what do you want to do

Comment: Is there a way to update the database or create a time-based trigger in postgres? Like in my case, if now()-exam_answer.time_started > duration, the exam_answer will be automatically updated to status = 2

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use view? For me it's good case to create view with calculated status field

Answer (score 1):

Django applications, like any other WSGI/web application, are only meant to handle request-response flows. If there aren't any requests, there is no activity and such changes will not happen.

You can either write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/) that's executed periodically by a cron job, but you run into the risk of possibly displaying incorrect data. You have elegant means at your disposal to compute the statuses before any related views start their processing, but this might be potentially a wasteful use of resources.

Your best bet might be to integrate a task scheduler with your application, such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Do not be discouraged because Celery seemingly runs in a concurrent multiprocess environment across several machines--the service can be configured to run in a single-thread and it provides a clean interface for scheduling such tasks that have to run at some exact point in the future.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way in postgres to do such stuff. Unfortunately, I can't find anything except by using pgAgent.

Like what you have said, I just end up updating my table whenever he goes to a page requesting to view his exams.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend pgAgent if just for the fact that tasks are unportable and your schema is transient by nature, since it is introspected from your models.

Comment: This cant be done directly in PostgreSQL. The closest you have is pgagent, but it basically wraps cron or similar as far as I know.  The problem basically is that PostgreSQL only handles things you can give discrete transaction contexts too.  You presumably don't want to hold open transactions for lengthy times so the actual tasks have to be initiated from outside PostgreSQL.